# Conversion from Longtext to decimal(17,4)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have been looking online for its soloution, but couldn't find a way to do it.
I have a table named as `temp` as an example:

```
incassoid  productid  productamount  amount    
---------  ---------  -------------  -------  
    1          1      50.00          50.0000                  
    2          1      40.00          40.0000                    
    3          1      50.00          50.0000
```

where the type of `productamount` is `longtext`, I want to convert into Decimal(17,4), So far I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN productamount Decimal(17,4);
```

But it gives me an error:

```
 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Decimal(17,4)' at line 1
```

I dont know what goes wrong, can some one please help in this.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MODIFY` keyword for the MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE temp MODIFY COLUMN productamount Decimal(17,4);
```